# POST Curl request missing body

Tags: curl, paypal, zsh

I'm trying to execute the following curl request

```
 curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer Token" \
  -H "PayPal-Request-Id: ID" \ 
-d '{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "desc",
  "type": "SERVICE",
  "category": "SOFTWARE",
  "image_url": "website/image",
  "home_url": "website"
}'
```

It spits back the following error:

```
{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"3d62fa9fd7b05","details":[{"location":"body","issue":"MISSING_REQUEST_BODY","description":"Request body is missing."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#INVALID_REQUEST","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
* Could not resolve host: Optional
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Optional
* Could not resolve host: and
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: and
* Could not resolve host: if
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: if
* Could not resolve host: passed,
* Closing connection 4
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: passed,
* Could not resolve host: helps
* Closing connection 5
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: helps
* Could not resolve host: identify
* Closing connection 6
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: identify
* Could not resolve host: idempotent
* Closing connection 7
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: idempotent
* Could not resolve host: requests
* Closing connection 8
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: requests
zsh: command not found: -d
```

Debug ID doesn't work and the link is for sometime deprecated and redirects to something useless.

Comment: Could you trim space between Content-Type and application/json after the colon like this: `Content-Type:application/json`

Comment: "Could not resolve host: Optional" indicates you used the word `Optional` somewhere in your command line but there's none in the shown command. Thus I suspect you're not showing us the command line you actually ran... Also: what OS/shell do you run this with?

Comment: @MalachiNoel : Why is this tagged php, if there is no PHP involved?

Comment: You seem to have a space in the end of the line `-H "PayPal-Request-Id: ID" \ `.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your output, it seems that the command line you used is different than the one you posted, because the output contains text from a comment in a PayPal sample, namely: `Optional and if passed, helps identify idempotent requests`.

The PayPal documentation contains the following sample:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
  -H "PayPal-Request-Id: <merchant-generated-ID>" \ // Optional and if passed, helps identify idempotent requests
-d '{
  "name": "Video Streaming Service",
  "description": "Video streaming service",
  "type": "SERVICE",
  "category": "SOFTWARE",
  "image_url": "https://example.com/streaming.jpg",
  "home_url": "https://example.com/home"
}'
```

When I execute the sample, the relevant output is:

```
* Connection #0 to host api-m.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token signature verification failed"}* Could not resolve host:  
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  
* Rebuilt URL to: Optional/
* Could not resolve host: Optional
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Optional
* Rebuilt URL to: and/
*   Trying 192.168.200.167...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

This looks similar to your output. Remove the comment. Also, be sure to remove whitespace after `\` to avoid `command not found: -d` - the whitespace causes the shell to assume the next line represents a new command.